# How do we protect our post data processing method in CodeIgniter controller from the external form?

Tags: codeigniter, controller, inject

I'm working on a small project with CodeIgniter which handling some post data submitted from the admin form page.
I do transfer the post data to a method in my controller and send it to the database.
Its working all the time.
Im thinking, what if someone make an external form with the exact same inputs name and action attribute with mine in the admin page (I dont know how to figure the inputs name out but this is just my wonder), and try to post some data to the controller? 
I try to use session but I wonder if there are any way to protect that kind of inject method?

Answer (score 0):

you can try before your form_validator with

```
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == base_url()){
    //form validator
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'You try to enter from an external web without permission');

    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do.

First, since this is an admin only page I assume you have some kind of login and user verification in place.

You can use session data to store the successful admin login.

```
//admin log in OK
$this->session->set_userdata('admin_logged_in', TRUE);
```

In the method that processes the form post, confirm the user is logged in

```
if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') !== TRUE)
{
    redirect('somewhere_else');
    return; //here in case the redirect call doesn't work
}
```

Second, since you are 'posting' to this page confirm that is the method the server has received - it MUST be post.  If you are using CI version => 3.0 the do this

```
if($this->input->method() !== 'post')
{
    //somebody is trying to fool you
    redirect('somewhere_else');
    return; //here in case the redirect call doesn't work
}
```

If you are using an earlier version of CI (before 3.0.x) do this

```
if(strtolower($this->server('REQUEST_METHOD') !== 'post')
{
    //somebody is trying to fool you
    redirect('somewhere_else');
    return; //here in case the redirect call doesn't work
}
```

You also might want to consider the case where the session info checks out but it was not a POST request. That is very suspicious to me and it might be wise to destroy the session before redirecting.